# How can i parse information in a HTML Telegram Message?

Tags: jenkins, jira, telegram, webhooks, jira-rest-api

i have integration with Jira and Telegram to send issue's comment when a git commit is done (I use Jenkins). Using a pipeline i can comment issues, but Telegram message looks so ugly. I want to modify this information before send message (deleted url link for example) to Telegram, in Jira this format is ok, Thank You!

Jira comments it's like this:

[image]

And Telegram shows this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, in Jira Automation, custom body message using .replaceAll method (Java) for regex:

```
Comentario: <b>{{issue.comments.last.body.replaceAll("\{panel\}.*?\{panel\}","").replaceAll.....
```

And we can use replaceAll a lot of times to create a new string starting from regex results.

[image]

Hope someone helps.